# Will I receive Android OTA updates after switching carriers?

Tags: ota-update, carriers

I currently own a Samsung Galaxy S5, purchased from AT&T.  It has what I presume is an AT&T version of the OS with an AT&T boot screen, etc.  Software updates are also delivered OTA via AT&T servers.  I am considering switching to T-Mobile and was wondering if/how I will receive updates after the switch.  Will I still get updates from the AT&T servers, or will I somehow be transferred to T-Mobile's system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a Galaxy S8 from Verizon and I switched to an MVNO which piggybacks on T-Mobile's network.  With the new carrier, the phone does not recognize the service and does not perform an update check.  However, after inserting the original SIM card, Verizon does allow the system update to be checked, the update to be downloaded, and installed.  I then have to switch the SIM card back to my MVNO.
Perhaps it works the same way with AT&T phones. May be worth a try.